# Where to get images for commercial use?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, background-removal

I need some product's image to edit on Photoshop for commercial use. I don't have a camera so I need images from some source. So can any one help me on this matter?

Comment: There are a ton of [stock image web sites](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/115/where-are-some-good-places-to-find-royalty-free-stock-images) where you can purchase images.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously plan a service which edits images. As suggested already, you can buy images. You should easily find tens of commercial image sellers. Also sources of free images exist. Do not publish anything which originally hadn't clear written statement that allows you to use them.

Some image sources will demand you to show the source or the photographer. That's often the case for free images. Also editing and business usage can be limited, so read the license with extreme care.

I believe you should also insert some before/after examples of images of objects which perhaps need some fixing and are taken with a smartphone without pro studio environment and lights. For this purpose you surely have a camera.

An example:

[image]

(The photo is taken from an older case [Get white background on product photos?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9242/get-white-background-on-product-photos))

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I exactly finding images for that. Your example is correct. I need images for 9 categories. But problem is, I don't have a camera or pro studio. Then what is the solution.

Comment: @souravjns The solution is already presented. Buy the images. There are tens of commercial image sellers such as Shutterstock, GettyImages, Adobe, etc...They have one problem: Individual images are already fine tuned. But you can show how you insert or remove something, change the colors or make compilations. A local photographer also can surely sell something. Do not expect you get business materials for free. Co-operation with a photographer can be productive, He can give some images if he sees that he can get something, too.