# Making an out-of-focus selfie into an ID photo

Tags: background-removal

I need an ID photo with a white background *(that's studio type)* but my best shot is only a self-portrait photograph. I need instructions to replace the out-of-focus background with white, and canvas the left & right sides to make it square.

**Here is the top source of the picture which is more clearer:**
*https://scontent-b-lax.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpa1/t31.0-8/171006_1390215815070_6123382_o.jpg?dl=1*
[image: Servant 2009]

I've already tried these online tools:

- [Clipping Magic](http://clippingmagic.com) - Its production is not good enough for something like a non-clear image.
- [Background Burner](http://www.bonanza.com/background_burner) - Uploading takes forever to complete maybe due to the security of a computer cafe/shop.

Can anyone help direct me to a tool that I can use in an internet cafe to make this kind of a self-portrait photo into an ID photo, then that would be great!

Comment: I'm not sure this is the place to ask people to do this kind of work. Have you taken a look at online tools such as Aviary? https://www.aviary.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for free work which is not within the defined scope of this site.

Comment: @spiral I don't have an Android nor an iOS, I only have an S40.

Comment: @Scott I change my mind and edit my question, I need the complete instructions, so I can do it quickly on my own in a matter of an hour, in a computer cafe/shop if there's no willing to help.

Comment: Welcome to GD Servant.  Asking for free work is not the purpose of GD.  Please edit your question with some effort on what you have tried and we can assist in helping but asking for work to be completed by the community is off-topic

Comment: So you ask someone to do it.. then edit to remove that.. then edit again to ask again for free work?

Comment: @Scott No.. I didn't removed that part of an option, I've just shortened it.

Comment: There are plenty of questions on the subject of [background removal](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/background-removal). I suggest you browse those questions to find a solution that works for you. As others have said, asking people to do your work for you is not okay on this site.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do this with something like Paint Shop Pro (other image-processing packages are available)

- Select the out-of-focus area [irregular selection] and *Sharpen* it.
- Invert the selection to select the rest of the image and make it a neutral colour (**not** white, an off-white)
- Invert the selection again to select the original area of your head and add a fuzzy shadow.

Or: get another photo! The above procedure will probably require a far longer time than simply retaking the photo, if the result is to be good. It's probably worth doing if you have to manipulate a one-off photo which can't be repeated.

Comment: The best option in my experience is to improve the hardware before the software. A good Camera Reflex will be a much better tool than the best software. What device are using you for this photo you want or need?